# Does Allah favor men in Islam?

Tags: women, men, equality

Does Allah favor men over women, or does he love us all equally?
I have read this: https://www.uua.org/re/tapestry/youth/bridges/workshop14/185708.shtml 
but I'm not sure as to if it is true?

Comment: Woman actually are more protected than man according to Islam. You have nice lecture [here](https://youtu.be/lWG9-LX47xk) that explains that and more.

Comment: Strictly speaking no, each one has his duties and favors Islam takes into account that both genders are different in many things be it abilities or strength or whatever. A man who is not in charge of his family for example has no right of obedience according to many scholars.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be reading propaganda against Islam or what non-Muslims think of Islam without having good base knowledge in the religion.

Allah says in the Quran:

> O mankind, indeed We have created you from male and female and made you peoples and tribes that you may know one another. *Indeed, the most noble of you in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you*. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted. (49:13)

Different rules apply to men and women in some cases because they are different. However, Allah loves people and honors people based on their piety, not their gender.